# Universal App / Flipable / w Tab Bar Controller and Split View

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, ipad, universal

I am trying to develop app frame with below features
Goal is to develop an universal screen flow that starts with a uiview similar to weather app and upon flip it loads uitabbar controller based view. and for iPad tabbar items should have split view attached to it.

An Universal Application
   - has a window and switch view controller (UI view controller)
Based on device
   - switches main window as usual
on iPhone
   - switch view controller for iphone has 2 view controllers such as settingsVC and systemVC
   - by default it loads the settings VC and
   - upon button click it flips to systemVC (similar to weather application)
   - systemVC has a tabbar controlled added to its view
   - this portion works fine

on iPad
   - i have a similar flipable screen with 2 VCs
   - now on systemVC have a uiview
   - i am adding a tabbarcontroller to its subview using IB and outlet

problem is half of uitabbar gets hidden below the screen. i tried changing values on IB nothings seems to work.

Just wanted to know, if I am on the right track and what could possibly be wrong.

I would highly appreciate any tips or concerns.

Thanks and Good Day!

Siva

Comment: I got it fixed. 
- Set the main window and switch view to full screen and nothing attached at top or bottom such as status bar, nav bar etc., 
- because it got redefined at the bottom most layer. 

hope it helps.